# Is there a way to filter AM and PM in time stamp?

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

[image]I have a column contains values like
12:45 PM
11:00 AM
.
.
ETC

I want to count time contains AM and time contains PM in this column

How to do this using select  MYSQL  ?
I tried:
(CASE WHEN start_booking_time LIKE'%AM%' THEN COUNT(id) ELSE 0 END),
(CASE WHEN start_booking_time LIKE'%PM%' THEN COUNT(id) ELSE 0 END),

[image]

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: What is that? `Timediff`?

Comment: @FanoFN
This is Start Booking Time 
From Bookings Table 
I want to count morning and evening thru AM A& PM

Comment: I don't see any expected outcome. Please add a table with the intendes results. Please also note uploading images as sample data is not allowed, this has to be provided as table. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are you counting? How does your complete data look like, not only this single column? Very sad you refuse to put sufficient effort in your question. In this case, it should better be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't far away

```
sum(CASE WHEN start_booking_time LIKE'%AM%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
sum(CASE WHEN start_booking_time LIKE'%PM%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```